# Redirect as a result of an fetch operation

Tags: javascript, express, redirect, fetch

I am building a simple website in clean JavaScript, using only fetch API.
It communicates with a backend running [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js).
When the user is logged in, it gets a session cookie.

My problem is that I want an redirect to a login page if the session is not valid, for any of the possible requests by the client.
I've tried from the server side to redirect to the login page:

```
res.status(301).redirect("/login.html");
```

I can see the redirect in the developer tools network tab of the web browser, and I can see that it follows it, and downloads the *login.html* file. But it doesn't seem to actually navigate to the page. Is it something I am missing here?

Is there a better approach to this problem? Of course I could do an extra check in the frontend every time I do a request, and then redirect it from there, but I want to avoid it if possible, as it will produce much extra code...

Comment: `fetch` only performs a request. It cannot redirect the current page on its own.

Comment: Returning 301 will only actively redirect if the browser itself has *visited* the page, rather than simply *fetching* it. You will have to perform the redirect in JS, as the answer shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to display `login.html` instead of just downloading it, you can check if the response was redirected after calling fetch, and setting `window.location.href` to `response.url` like so:

```js
fetch(*fetch config*).then(res => {
  // Check if the response was redirected and then change the current URL
  if (res.redirected) window.location.href = res.url;
})
```

Comment: Thanks,, yes that works. I'll just have to update the code in many places.